# Circular include statements leading to link error

Tags: c++, linker, g++, linker-errors

I have a large project (20+ files) but I managed to set up this small example which recreates my problem. Essentially I have one file (`A.cpp`) including a second file (`B.cpp`), but that second file needs several of the variables and functions from the first file. Observe:

**A.h:**

```
#ifndef _A_H_
#define  _A_H_
static void foo(int _something);
#endif // #ifndef _A_H_
```

**A.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

using namespace std;

static void foo(int _something)
{
   cout << _something << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   B *b;

   foo ( 123 ); // So we don't get that pesky defined-not-used warning
   b = new B ();
   b->display ( 123 );
}
```

**B.h:**

```
#ifndef _B_H_
#define  _B_H_
#include "A.h"

class B
{
   public:
      B();
      ~B();
      void display ( int x );
};
#endif // #ifndef _B_H_
```

**B.cpp:**

```
#include "B.h"

void B::display ( int x )
{
   foo ( x );
}
```

And I am compiling it like so, `g++ -Wall A.cpp B.cpp -o main` but then I get this error:

```
A.h:3:13: warning: ‘void foo(int)’ used but never defined [enabled by default]
/tmp/ccFwfZa6.o: In function `main':
A.cpp:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `B::B()'
/tmp/ccM8SNBK.o: In function `B::display(int)':
B.cpp:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `foo(int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can tell it's a link error, but I can't tell why I am getting that error.

**EDIT:**

In my original code I am *still* getting an error, this time it's about the multiple definition of an integer, here is the error I am getting:

```
B.o:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `some_var'
A.o:(.bss+0x4034): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

and I am creating the variable `some_var` like so

**A.h:**

```
#ifndef _A_H_
#define  _A_H_
static void foo(int _something);
int some_var;
#endif // #ifndef _A_H_
```

How is it possible that `some_var` would get defined more than once when I have those conditional guards?

Comment: See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812769/static-function-declared-but-not-defined-in-c - there is no need to declare the function as static when it's global, and doing so restricts its usage to the compilation unit in which it is declared.

Comment: Remove static from foo, and define the constructor for class B.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_A_H_`, `_B_H_`) are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: Despite the title, there's nothing circular here.

Comment: @PeteBecker Good to know, I was following somebody else's convetions

Comment: "I have a large project (20+ files)" -- no, your project is *tiny*. A large(ish) project will have 1000+ files.

Comment: @PeteBecker Not circular? Are you sure? To me it looks like `A.cpp`-> `B.ccp` -> `A.cpp`

Comment: @EmployedRussian What I meant was "I have a project which I can not exactly cut and paste here"

Comment: @puk - b.cpp includes b.h; b.h includes a.h; a.h includes nothing. a.cpp includes b.h and a.h; again, b.h includes a.h and a.h includes nothing. No circle.

Comment: @PeteBecker The problem still persists, please see edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem **now** is that each source file that `#include`s `a.h` gets a definition of `int some_var;`. In general, variables should be **declared** in headers and **defined** in one source file. So in your header you need

`extern int some_var;`

and in one source file (presumably a.cpp)

`int some_var;`

Comment: oh, I thought extern was "somewhere else out there in the universe" not "in the source file which will obviously call me". I will try that

Comment: I am such an idiot, obviously, instead of having `extern blablabla` statements in B.h, it makes more sense to have them in A.h

Comment: @puk - extern **is** "somewhere else out there in the universe". If you define it in a.cpp, then in b.cpp the `extern` means that it's defined in some other translation unit; in a.cpp, it means that it's defined later on.

Comment: OK now things got even weirder, now if I remove those `extern` statements, things magically work regardless...I had a problem, I fixed it, and now it's as if I never had the problem to begin with

Comment: @puk - that's not necessarily weird. If `some_var` isn't used anywhere other than the source file where it's defined, then you don't need an `extern` declaration.

Comment: WOW that was extremely painful to debug. I will accept this, but I will answer this question as well, in case someone runs into this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You have no B::B() body at all. Add one, and don't forget about destructor.

Also, remove static from foo().

Comment: Yes, I just realized the `B()` part. Removed static and it appears to work. Will test it out on my main code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Pete Becker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593860/pete-becker) I figured out the problem, and it stemmed mostly from a lack of understanding of all things C/C++.

1. `extern` statements are not meant to only be used in header files referencing other header files (ie. in "B.h" writing `extern int a` where `a` is defined in "A.c") but also in the original header files (in this case "A.h")
2. I thought, incorrectly, that a definition needed an equals sign (ie. `int a = 1`) whereas `int a` is also a definition. I was, thus, defining my variable in "A.h" when I should have been declaring it like so `extern int a` in "A.h".
3. After fixing the above 2, I kept getting `undefined reference to a` (I literally thought the compiler and linker were taking the piss). I was searching for `int a=...` in "A.cpp" and as clear as day it was being defined. Turns out this definition was *inside* a function, and therefore was never being defined.
4. If all else fails, edit your source files in a trivial way (ie. delete a word and type it again) to force a compilation) as I find changing the header files does not always result in full compilations.