# C++ Using static class function from another header, "class_name" has not been declared

Tags: c++, static-functions

**EDIT:***thanks for pointing me in the right direction of circular dependency. I tried removing **#include "datastructure.h"** from *Mathfg.h*, and I added a "Class ArithmeticTree" in "Matfg.h" to forward declare it, but I get another error inside the CleanExpression function: 

**cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::basic_string::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int remove(const char*)'**. When I hover over the word "remove", Qt tells me I have "too many arguments". This is on the one line of code that Calculator::CleanExpression comprises.*

I am writing a math parser and I have created a header file *Mathfg* which includes a *Calculator* class that handles inputs. So far I have a static function called *CleanExpression* which simply removes whitespace from the input string. 
I saw a somewhat similar problem here: [Static function declared but not defined in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812769/static-function-declared-but-not-defined-in-c), but I could not apply the answers there to my own problem. 
(I left out irrelevant sections such as the implementation of the *Node* struct, but it all works, except for the *CleanExpression* call.)

## Mathfg.h

```
#ifndef MATHFG_H
#define MATHFG_H

#include <string>
#include "datastructure.h"
using namespace std;

class Mathfg
{
private:
    Mathfg();
};

class Calculator
{
private:
    Calculator();
public:
    static void CleanExpression(string& expression)
    {
        expression.erase(remove(expression.begin(), expression.end(), ' '), expression.end());
    }
};

#endif // MATHFG_H
```

**Note: I do not use a source file for Mathfg.h.**

## Datastructure.h

In another header, *"Datastructure.h"*, I fix the input and produce an output. I wanted to call the static function *CleanExpression* from *"Mathfg.h"*, but I get the error: **'Calculator' has not been declared**.

```
#ifndef DATASTRUCTURE_H
#define DATASTRUCTURE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "mfg\mathfg.h"
using namespace std;

struct ArithmeticTree
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        // Doing some unrelated stuff here
    };

public:
    ArithmeticTree()
    {

    }
    ArithmeticTree(string expression_in)
    {
        Calculator::CleanExpression(expression_in);     // <- Here's the problem!
        // Doing some unrelated stuff here
    }

    // Doing some unrelated stuff here
};

#endif // DATASTRUCTURE_H
```

**Note: I do not use a source file for Datastructure.h.**

## What *does* work:

In my game loop, I can successfully run this code:

```
std::string str = "2 +3-4 /      5";
cout << "Cleaning string:\t'" << str << "'\n";
Calculator::CleanExpression(str);
cout << "Cleaned:\t\t'" << str << "'\n";
```

...which outputs:

```
Cleaning string:    '2 +3-4 /      5'
Cleaned:            '2+3-4/5'
```

...but when I try to call *Calculator::CleanExpression* from within *"Datastructure.h"* - or more specifically, from within *ArithmeticTree*'s constructor - I get the aforementioned error. I never created a *Calculator* or *Mathfg* object anywhere in my code; I just call its static function like I would normally expect it to behave.
I am sure I have misunderstood how static functions work in C++, which probably also is the cause of my error. 
I would really like some tips on how to go about fixing this problem! 
I am using *Qt Creator 4.2.1* and *MinGW 5.3.0 32bit2*.

Comment: You have a circular header file dependency... `mathfg.h` depends on `datastructure.h` which depends on `mathfg.h` and so on and on. You need to break the dependency chain somehow, like not including `datastructure.h` in `mathfg.h` (since `mathfg.h` doesn't seem to actually need anything from `datastructure.h`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I edited the question to reflect my changes in the code, but this still doesn't seem to fix the problem.